# Add a navigation menu item using MySQL

Tags: menus, mysql, navigation

I want to insert Wordpress nav menu items into MySQL using PHP.  I dont think i can use wp_create_nav_menu() because I need to build a preliminary menu from the categories (over 100 cats!) then a lower level admin can modify/adjust/refine.  I dont think the wp_create_nav_menu() actually updates the MySQL db's.

I can surely figure this out but just wondering if someone can give me a head start.

```
Update wp_posts 
Update wp_term_relationships
update wp_term_taxonomy
update wp_terms

set             "post_author" => 1, 
                "post_date" => '2017-12-15 09:37:18', 
                "post_date_gmt" => '2017-12-15 09:37:18', 
                "post_content" => '', 
                "post_title" => 'Storage', 
                "post_excerpt" => '', 
                "post_status" => 'publish', 
                "comment_status" => 'closed', 
                "ping_status" => 'closed', 
                "post_password" => '', 
                "post_name" => 'home-garden-kitchen', 
                "to_ping" => '', 
                "pinged" => '', 
                "post_modified" => '2018-12-03 14:29:13', 
                "post_modified_gmt" => '2018-12-03 20:29:13', 
                "post_content_filtered" => '', 
                "post_parent" => 0, 
                "menu_order" => 97, 
                "post_type" => 'nav_menu_item',     
                "post_mime_type" => '', 
                "comment_count" => 0
```

etc, etc...

Answer (score 1):

My Bad, `wp_create_nav_menu()` does insert MySQL

Comment: Note that if it didn't, there are still other WP ways of doing it, nav menus are a combination of a private taxonomy and a post type